# Assembly Language subroutines

Tags: assembly, stack, subroutine

This section has me thoroughly confused. I have an example problem that I am hoping someone can break down into steps for me so that I may absorb how it is done to apply to other problems.

```
mc:   call subr
mr:   mov  [val],ax
subr: push ax
      push bx
      push cx
      add  ax,dx
      pop  ax
      pop bx
      pop cx
      ret
```

The book asks what the hex value in the sp and ax register will be for when the code returns from the subroutine and reaches the instruction `mr: mov [val],ax`. `sp=0100 ax=0002`, but I have no clue as to how to arrive at these answers.

The instruction `mc: call subr` saves the address of the next sequential instruction `mr: mov [val],ax` on the stack so the subroutine can correctly return. The absolute address in memory where the return address is saved is `1120E`. Can anyone please elaborate on this as well?

```
registers given:
ax = 0000  bx = 0001  cx = 0002  dx = 0004
si = 0000  di = FFFF  bp = 0080  sp = 0100
cs = 1000  ds = 1100  es = 1110  ss = 1111
```

Comment: Which type of assembly language is shown here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call at `mc:` will save the current address, so when the `subr:` returns, control will start again at `mr:`.

Since `subr:` pushes ax, bx, and cx in that order. It then pops ax, bx, and cx in that order, so what was pushed from cx gets popped into ax (and vice versa). The effect of these is to swap ax and cx. The `add ax, dx` has no real effect on the result produced, because immediately after adding dx to ax, it pops ax off the stack. The `add` does affect the flags, but nothing here does anything based on the flags, so at least in the code you've shown, that doesn't mean much either.

After control returns to `mr:`, it writes the value in `ax` to memory, and then flows back into `subr:`, thus swapping ax and cx back to where they started.

IOW, the whole this is a very slow, roundabout way of achieving roughly the same effect as:

```
mc: mov [val], cx
    ret
```

As far as the absolute address goes, there's not much to say. In particular, chances are pretty good that if you run the same code again, it may be loaded at a different address, o the address saved on the stack may be entirely different.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think I understand the push and pop better now, but in what instance is `sp` changed? I updated the original post to show the registers given, so maybe you can help explain how I might calculate the absolute address with these values.

Comment: @raphnguyen: For the absolute address, you'd need the PC register, which isn't included in those you listed. `sp` is changed by anything that pushes or pops the stack (including the implicit push in a `call` and the implicit pop in a `ret`).

Comment: Hmm strange, I wonder why the book chose 1120E for the absolute address out of a group of five addresses. So since there are 3 `push` calls and 3 `pop` calls, they cancel each other out? I can't seem to find the section corresponding to the behavior of `sp`. Does it increment with each `push` and decrement with each `pop`?

Comment: Yes, they should cancel each out out. Yes, it's decremented (by two) with each push, and incremented by two with each pop, at least in 16-bit mode. In 32-bit mode, the increment/decrement would be 4.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this.